# How to test object that pushes values to using Reactive Extensions via `Sample` method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I have a class called `ValuePusher` with a property named `Value` and receives a dependency of type `ValueReceiver`, also with a property named `Value`. The former class arranges to 'push' values to an instance of the latter class via a `System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<int>` object. Initially it pushes values one for one, but later it will restrict the amount of values pushed using the `Sample` method  - note the commented-out call to this method in the code below:

```cs
public sealed class ValuePusher : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ValueReceiver _receiver;
    private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;
    private readonly Subject<int> _subject;

    private int _value;

    public ValuePusher(ValueReceiver receiver, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
        _scheduler = scheduler;

        // Arrange to push values to `receiver` dependency
        _subject = new Subject<int>();
        _subject.ObserveOn(_scheduler)
                //.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), _scheduler)
                .SubscribeOn(_scheduler)
                .Subscribe(i => PushCurrentValueToReceiver());
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            _subject.OnNext(0);
        }
    }

    private void PushCurrentValueToReceiver()
    {
        _receiver.Value = Value;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subject?.OnCompleted();
        _subject?.Dispose();
    }
}

public class ValueReceiver
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I write a unit test for the code above, involving a `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.TestScheduler`, which passes:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[Timeout(1000)]
public void ReceiverReceivesValueFromPusherViaScheduler()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var receiver = new ValueReceiver();

    using (var pusher = new ValuePusher(receiver, scheduler))
    {
        scheduler.Start();
        pusher.Value = 1;
        scheduler.AdvanceBy(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, receiver.Value);
    }
}
```

However, if uncomment the call to `Sample` method the test fails to complete and times-out. How can I change the test code or the production code to verify that values are pushed to the receiving object when `Sample` is in use?

Source code: https://github.com/DanStevens/StackOverflow71409012

Comment: The Sample is set to 50ms, but you only AdvanceBy 1 Tick. Shouldn't you advance at least 500000 ticks, before you get the first sample?

Comment: If I  remove `scheduler.Start()` and do `scheduler.AdvanceBy(500000)` instead of 1, it works.

Comment: @Magnus - You should post an answer so that the OP can accept. Accepted answers are much more valuable on this site.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it times out, seems to be the combination of `.Sample(...)` and `scheduler.Start()`.

`scheduler.Start()` tries execute everything that has been scheduled, but I think `Sample()` keeps scheduling a sample, and thus `scheduler.Start()` never finishes.

So if you remove `scheduler.Start()`, and do this instead:

```cs
...
// Following line instead of scheduler.Start(), needed because of the .SubscribeOn(...) call
scheduler.AdvanceBy(1);

pusher.Value = 1;
scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50).Ticks);
Assert.AreEqual(1, receiver.Value);
...
```

it should work with or without the call to `.Sample(...)`.

[Edit] as per Dan Stevens' comment.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer, Magnus. I was eventually able to work out the correct answer, but unfortunately your answer isn't quite correct. Removing the `scheduler.Start()` does remove the block, but the assertion fails. What is needed in place of `scheduler.Start()` is `scheduler.AdvanceBy(1)`. I think the reason is that this is needed in order for the observer and subscriber to be set up. If you edit your answer to mention this, I can give you the credit 

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn I had seen it working, without the first `.AdvanceBy`, but you're right, it doesn't work. I'll do the edit.

Comment: You're right - the first `.AdvanceBy` is needed, but only because the subscription logic is run on the TestScheduler, via the `SubscribeOn` call.